# Calculate Z* of confidence interval

Tags: statistics

I am trying to figure out how to figure out the z* for a 88% confidence interval.

I have tried searching on google but most sites didn’t help and any that I found I didn’t feel were explained clear enough for me to understand.

Comment: Hint: take the remaining area, halve it, and find the z-score corresponding to that area.

Comment: @SeanRoberson once I get the halved value how do I calculate the zscore mean or standard deviation?

Comment: You don't need it. Find the value inside the table as close you can.

Comment: The z-values that cut 6% from each tail of a standard normal distribution are $\pm 1.555)$ found in R as `qnorm(c(.06, .94))` which returns $\pm 1.554774,$ where `qnorm` is the inverse CDF of standard normal. This means that $P(-1.555 < Z < 1.555) \approx 0.88:$ in R, `diff(pnorm(c(-1.555, 1.555)))` returns 
0.8800539, where `pnorm` is the CDF. I don't know what format of normal tables you are using, but from the answer I hope you can figure out the method for your particular tables. With most normal tables you will get only about 2-place accuracy, so maybe $\pm 1.56$ is where to look first.